# Matching pattern using reg ex and re.sub

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to remove the following pattern from some data and am getting mixed results.

`--endof["somerandomtext"]`

Basically the text always starts with `--endof["` and ends with `"]` and the words in between change.
The line of code I am using that is not working currently working all the time.

```
d = re.sub('--+([a-zA-Z0-9_"-\[]*)+\]', " ", d)
```

I am new to trying to parse data using re.sub or any method. I have been just guessing at how to try and make this line work, and I probably have something wrong that is causing me problems.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variation of @Hexagon's answer:

```
s = re.sub('--endof\[[^]]+]', '', s)
```

This removes a string that starts with `--endof[`, followed by any number of non-`]`s (`[^]]+`), followed by a `]`. Works for any text that does not contain closing brackets.

Answer (score 2):

To remove text starting with `--endof["` and ending with `"]`, you should match these as exact characters, and match a substring in the middle.

Because `[` and `]` have special meaning in a regular expression, you need to escape them with `\` (as correctly stated in a comment, `]` doesn't have to be escaped here, leaving it escpaed for extra clarity).

In this example, the substring in the middle is composed of one or more letters and digits (hence the `+`). It can be altered as needed.

```
str = re.sub('--endof\["[a-zA-Z0-9]+"\]', "", str)
```

To break this up further -

`--endof` matches these characters exactly.
`\[` matches the character `[`.
`"` matches the character `"`.
`[a-zA-Z0-9]+` matches a string consisting of one or more letters and digits (`+` is for "one or more").
`"` again matches the character `"`.
`\]` matches the character `]` (and can be specified as `]` alone).

Comment: There is no need to put a backslash in front of the `]`. It is not a special character unless a part of a range.

Comment: @DYZ True. It helps with clarity.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am not sure why, but the line of code above does not completely remove the comment.

Comment: @XenPanda I guess it depends on what characters are expected to be inside the brackets. As in @DYZ's answer, `[^]]` can be used to pick up anything which isn't `]`, which is very inclusive, and might be what you need.

Comment: That is probably the case, I think there may have been a - somewhere in there so that probably caused it to fail. The error reporting isn't very helpful trying to figure out why it fails...at least to me.